# How do I preserve newlines in a quoted string in Bash?

Tags: bash

I'm creating a script to automate the creation of apache virtual hosts. Part of my script goes like this:

```
MYSTRING="<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName $NEWVHOST
DocumentRoot /var/www/hosts/$NEWVHOST

...

"
echo $MYSTRING
```

However, the line breaks in the script are being ignored. If I echo the string, is gets spat out as one line.

How can I ensure that the line breaks are printed?

Answer (score 216, accepted):

Add quotes to make it work:

```
echo "$MYSTRING"
```

Look at it this way:

```
MYSTRING="line-1
line-2
line3"

echo $MYSTRING
```

this will be executed as:

```
echo line-1 \
line-2 \
line-3
```

i.e. `echo` with three parameters, printing each parameter with a space in between them.

If you add quotes around `$MYSTRING`, the resulting command will be:

```
echo "line-1
line-2
line-3"
```

i.e. `echo` with a single string parameter which has three lines of text and two line breaks.

Comment: Thanks, now I finally understand why echo works like this - because it parses the input as arguments! I wish I read that somewhere earlier.

Comment: Tangentially, see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable