# bash - grep? sed? to remove lines of text from a variable

Tags: bash, sed, grep, text-processing

I have a variable full of text, its actually a git log. Each line of the git log has an id (a JIRA id), which is either IPAD or MIPO.

I want to filter the git output and only show one or the other

So far I have this:

```
RAW_NOTES=`git log $LAST_REVISION..master --pretty=format:"%h %ar %s"`
echo "Raw git notes: $RAW_NOTES"
```

then i can filter it using

```
RELEASE_NOTES=`echo "$RAW_NOTES" | grep "$JIRA_KEY"`
echo $RELEASE_NOTES
```

However.... RAW_NOTES has nice formatting and line breaks, RELEASE_NOTES loses all my line breaks.

How can I either preserve formatting, or use some other text filtering command to remove certain lines of text that matches.

example input:

```
IPAD did this
IPAD did that
MIPO Im another comment
IPAD something else
IPAD bla bla
MIPO hello 
MIPO doodle do
```

and i want the output to be

```
MIPO Im another comment
MIPO hello 
MIPO doodle do
```

Thanks

Comment: [Related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2414150/183066)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

git log provides filtering like so:

```
git log --grep="$JIRA_KEY"
```

Comment: FYI, you would need to set IFS like `IFS='\n'` before printing $RELEASE_NOTES.

Answer (score 1):

Try echoing with quotes, like this:

```
echo "$RELEASE_NOTES"
```

Comment: This also solves my problem, but I might as well filter at the source - the git log, as @Pumbaa80 suggested. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based on your sample input you can try anyone of these -

```
sed -n '/MIPO/p' filename

sed '/MIPO/!d' filename

awk '/MIPO/' filename

grep "MIPO" filename
```