# Save command output in string variable keeping newlines

Tags: linux, bash

I have a script that transforms a file's data, in order to work more efficiently I want to alter the data in memory and then dump it to the file.
Supose I want to modify a file that contains this:

```
> This is a line
> this is other line
```

I use a sed command to replace the '>' symbols with '#' ones:

```
transform_output=$(eval "sed ${sed_args[@]} $file" 2>&1)
echo -e $transform_output
```

I get the output:

```
# This is a line # this is other line
```

rather than the output I would like to have wich is:

```
# This is a line
# this is other line
```

1. How do I save the output in the string variable keeping the newlines?
2. How could I add a line at the begining of the variable that contains "#ADDED LINE#" and save that in a file?

(the file I want to obtain would be):

```
#ADDED LINE#
# This is a line
# this is other line
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [how do I preserve newlines in a quoted string in bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414150/how-do-i-preserve-newlines-in-a-quoted-string-in-bash)

Comment: It might be. I didn't find it when I researched before asking, found anything else but what I was looking for

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Quoting is used to prevent word-splitting at whitespace:

   `echo -e "$transform_output"`
2. Group the command with another echo:

   `{ echo "#ADDED LINE#"; echo -e "$transform_output" } > file`

Comment: Thanks a lot, man!
Can't believe it was such stupidly simple!