# How can I write new line - Echo command

Tags: bash, echo

I have a log file and simple bash script:

```
echo -e "$date $totalsize $dupsize $per" > log.txt
```

But when I execute this script, it write first line of log.txt and show me just last data.

I tried \n but does not working.

How can I write to new line when I execute this script?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414150/how-do-i-preserve-newlines-in-a-quoted-string-in-bash

Comment: @theMarceloR Thats not related to this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume what you mean is that you want to append to the `log.txt`? In that case, use:

```
echo -e "$date $totalsize $dupsize $per" >> log.txt
```

Note the `>>` which means append.

Using `>` will create a new file (overwrite it) each time it's run, containing whatever you echo to it.

Comment: @volkanasr Your welcome, glad to help. (Don't forget to accept answer if you feel it's complete.)