# How to preserve line endings when extracting git commit messages in a bash script?

Tags: git, bash, mingw, git-svn, line-endings

I am using git svn to access a SVN server.
I am trying to write a script that converts and copy all SVN tags into git tags.

I found this:
http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/02/16/convert-git-svn-tag-branches-to-real-tags.html

And this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3357357/882697

To create that:

```
git for-each-ref refs/remotes/origin/tags | cut -d / -f 5- |
while read ref
do
    msg=`git log --format=%B -n 1 origin/tags/"$ref"`
    echo $msg
done
```

The `git log` command works well in the mingw bash (from git install). 
But when launching the script from the same mingw bash, the line endings are stripped.
I tried to added `\r`:

```
msg=`echo $msg | sed 's/\n/\r\n/'`
```

But it doesn't work either...

Could someone help me please? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try at least putting double-quotes:

```
echo "${msg}"
```

(see "[how do I preserve newlines in a quoted string in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2414157/6309)")

That will avoid echo interpreting the output of `$msg` content (doing [field splitting or pathname expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29378567/6309)).

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer and for the useful links. Not only did I learn a trickery about bash but now I also have http://www.shellcheck.net/ in my bookmarks! Thanks again!

Comment: @Plouff you are most welcome! Regarding spellcheck, here this is about https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2086.

Comment: I haven't noticed that the output of spellcheck provides links to the documentation. Thanks again for this hint :)!